# How to order table pushing in front rows that has either one or another non empty column (Postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
id
field_1 (json, nullable)
field_2 (json, nullable)
field_3 (text)
created_at (datetime)
```

I need to select data from this table ordering it in a way that first will be all rows containing a non-empty **field_1** or **field_2** (still ordered by created_at) and then all other rows with null **field_1** and **field_2** (ordered by created_at)

Is there a way to do it with Postgresql?

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide sample output but if I understand correctly:

```
select * from tablename
order by created_at ,
         field_1 asc nulls last , 
         field_2 asc nulls last
```

Answer (score 0):

You can order by booleans, keepings in mind that `false` sorts first by default

```
Order by (field1 is not null or field2 is not null) desc, created_at
```